# ios - how to listen for boot up

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

Is there a notification in iOS so i can know when the phone is rebooted ?  I'd like an event posted to the notification Center for example when the phone is completely booted just like android's onBootComplete broadcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is **NO Direct Documented API** available for this. As when the iPhone is restarted the application will be in **Not Running** state. Please refer [Docs for understanding Execution States for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3).

Although you can ask the system to relaunch your application on certain incoming events. 
Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system to handle incoming events. If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens:

1. For location apps:

   - The system receives a location update that meets the app’s configured criteria for delivery.
   - The device entered or exited a registered region. (Regions can be geographic regions or iBeacon regions.)
2. For audio apps, the audio framework needs the app to process some data. (Audio apps include those that play audio or use the microphone.)
3. For Bluetooth apps:

   - An app acting in the central role receives data from a connected peripheral.
   - An app acting in the peripheral role receives commands from a connected central.
4. For background download apps:

   - A push notification arrives for an app and the payload of the notification contains the content-available key with a value of 1.
   - The system wakes the app at opportunistic moments to begin downloading new content.
   - For apps downloading content in the background using the NSURLSession class, all tasks associated with that session object either completed successfully or received an error.
   - A download initiated by a Newsstand app finishes.

In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the device before the app can be launched automatically into the background by the system.
 Referenced from [Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW31).